# Resharper code format linebreaks

Tags: c#, resharper, code-formatting

Im trying to setup the code formatting in ReSharper. Limiting each line to a maximum count of characters, it seems to want to place casts on a separate line. Like so:

```
string mystring =
    (string)
        MyStringConverter.convert(toconvert, typeof(string), null, null);
```

I cant seem to be able to find the correct combination of settings to not have this on three lines. Im looking for something like this:

```
string mystring = (string) MyStringConverter.convert(
    toconvert, typeof(string), null, null);
```

Where the linebreak occurs is not *that* important, I guess I cant be to picky when I want to limit the line length. But three lines is a bit much.

Does anyone know the/any correct combination of settings to make it only cut the line once?

Answer (score 0):

I don;t think it's because of any setting. 
Probaly, Alt+Ctrl+F would fix it by self.

Comment: How do you mean? Its the formatter that places the breaks like that, not me. Although I invoke it with rightclick -> code cleanup, but Alt+Ctrl+F is just a shortcut for that I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you place a **parenthesis** at **beginning** of a line ReSharper will keep the newline before it.
Try:

```
string mystring = (string) MyStringConverter.convert
                       (toconvert, typeof(string), null, null);
```